# How to estimate the age of my Yahoo! Account

Tags: yahoo-account

I'm trying to estimate how old my Yahoo! account is, but I can't find this information anywhere on my profile. Any idea on where this could be displayed or a way to guess it? Unfortunately, there's no old mail there to help me estimating it.

(It's the first account I've registered, ever, so I'm curious :D)

Comment: We're talking about the late 90s, so that's in another life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to:

> http://pulse.yahoo.com/

and click "Profile" on the left-hand side navigation.  It will bring up your Yahoo! Profile page.  In the upper right-hand corner, there is some small text that says `Member since: ab/cd/efgh`.

Comment: Thanks! Although the date seems incorrect (it states 2000 but I recall registering it before that), I guess they migrated the account at some point and the date was lost. Too bad!

Comment: AFAIK, my date on my profile matches when I signed up, so...glad to help! :)

Comment: Yahoo Pulse no longer exists and this no longer works.

Answer (score 10):

You need to get into the [privacy dashboard](https://yahoo.mydashboard.oath.com/) to see this information now.

To do this, go to your account → *Preferences* and click on the **Privacy Dashboard** link under *MY LOCATIONS*. There, under *YOUR ACCOUNT* → *Your products*, the first box should show you the date since you are a member.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go to this [link](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?_uiFocus=answers&q=select%20*%20from%20answers.getbycategory%20where%20category_id%3D2115500137%20and%20type%3D%22resolved%22#h=select%20*%20from%20social.profile%20where%20guid%3Dme). It will create the following query for the Yahoo database:

```
select * from social.profile where guid=me
```

Click the "Test" button and it will return some XML. Then find (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) the tag called `MemberSince` and you've got your date.

Comment: It should be mentioned that you need to be logged in for this to work.

Comment: This no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to your sent folder or inbox and find the oldest email there.

Comment: Unfortunately, all my emails were apparently deleted by Yahoo at some point

Comment: @Luk They deleted the e-mails most probably due to lack of activity for a long period of time. I encoutered this issue too with my Hotmail account.